# How to get data from a selected datagrid cell in DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
How can I refer to cell "org2"?
I want to get the name of the organization that I have selected.
```

but I get information about the whole row and I get the whole list of organizations from that row, not the selected cell.I want to delete or correct this information

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ФИО" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Организация" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Org}" 
                                  Margin="-2" 
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                  HeadersVisibility="None" 
                                  CanUserAddRows="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" 
                                                    Header="Org" 
                                                    Binding="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to bind the `SelectedItem` of the inner, nested DataGrid to some property of your DataContext/ViewModel or use a `SelectionChanged` or `SelectedCellsChanged` event handler for the inner DataGrid.

Comment: Thank you so much)) I tried to address in different ways. but it didn’t work, but everything worked out)) SelectionChanged helped .. I was embarrassed that I gave the name to the inner DataGrid, but when I write  it in the code, I write "The name does not exist in current context"
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Org}   Name="innerDG" " 
can you explain why?